# How to restrict FloatField dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want restriction of weight(FloatField in `redirectLink`), `max_value` will change dynamically. But can not understand how can I implement those codes in CreateView or in Models.py.

**Here is my code:**

**models.py**

```
class MinMaxFloat(models.FloatField):
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        super(MinMaxFloat, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 'max_value' : self.max_value}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(MinMaxFloat, self).formfield(**defaults)

class redirectLink(models.Model):
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(shortenUrl, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.URLField()
    country = CountryField(multiple=False, blank=True, null=True)
    weight = MinMaxFloat(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0)
```

My question is how can I add `max_value` restriction as below in **CreateView** or in **Models.py**?

```
max_value = redirectLink.objects.filter(parameter=Shortenurl).aggregate(Sum('weight')).weight__sum
#Shortenurl(variable) is a specific parameter
```

Comment: First of all, the Django way to restrict min and max value is using the [**`MinValueValidator`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) and [**`MaxValueValidator`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator)s.

Comment: okay, how can I add this condition `max_value = redirectLink.objects.filter(parameter=Shortenurl).aggregate(Sum('weight')).weight__sum` in the limit_value of `MaxValueValidator`?

Comment: Better do those validations in your model forms using `clean()` method